# Pip on Windows won't install anything

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip

I'm trying to get Python 3.6 with numpy and openCV setup on a windows 10 machine. I have python 3.6.8 installed with pip 18.1. When I try to install anything with pip, regardless of the package, I get the same result:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D135A3AE48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D135A3ABE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D135A3A8D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D135A3A7B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001D135A3A9B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/numpy/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

I've tried updating pip, and it tells me that it's already up-to-date. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was some proxy issue on my company's network. Using --proxy after pip install numpy worked.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code

```
python3 -m pip install <pkg>
```

Comment: This is what I get:

C:\Users\tglenn17>python3 -m pip install numpy
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I've tried "python -m pip install numpy" and it does the same as when I just do "pip install numpy"

Comment: In the command prompt you will have to first get into the 'Scripts' folder.                                               something like cd C:.....\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts. You will have to find the path of your Scripts folder. If you search in the folder, you will get. After that try the pip install command

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. This sets pypi.org and files.pythonhosted.org as trusted hosts to ignore SSL errors.
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

Answer from this question: [pip install fails with "connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)